# Rendering a list in a Django template

Tags: python, django, list, csv, for-loop

Hi I am having trouble displaying my list to the template. In the console it prints all. However when I do a print after the for loop, I only get the last line of the list.

Here is my code:

```
    if 'process_udr' in request.POST:          

        #API Url for UDR History
        apiUrl_udr ='http://apiurl'

        #API Get Variable for UDR History
        response_udr = urllib2.urlopen(apiUrl_udr)
        reader = csv.reader(response_udr)

        for udr_rows in reader:
            print udr_rows

        payload = {'usr': usr, 'usrpw': usrpw, 'response': response, 'response_2': response_2, 'response_udr': response_udr, 'udr_rows': udr_rows,}

        return render_to_response(template, payload, context_instance=RequestContext(request))                

    else:

        None
```

The results I see printed from the for loop in the console:

```
['09/18/14', '08:00:00', '09/18/14', '08:00:00', 'XXXXXXXXXXX', 'GRP-XXXXXXXXXXX', 'DEFAULT', 'spostmv', '57565106', '0', '0', '19854']
['09/18/14', '09:00:00', '09/18/14', '09:00:00', 'XXXXXXXXXXX', 'GRP-XXXXXXXXXXX', 'DEFAULT', 'spostmv', '71792666', '0', '0', '20994']
['09/18/14', '10:00:00', '09/18/14', '10:00:00', 'XXXXXXXXXXX', 'GRP-XXXXXXXXXXX', 'DEFAULT', 'spostmv', '32902589', '0', '0', '30552']
['09/18/14', '11:00:00', '09/18/14', '11:00:00', 'XXXXXXXXXXX', 'GRP-XXXXXXXXXXX', 'DEFAULT', 'spostmv', '46560924', '0', '0', '26552']
['09/18/14', '12:00:00', '09/18/14', '12:00:00', 'XXXXXXXXXXX', 'GRP-XXXXXXXXXXX', 'DEFAULT', 'spostmv', '76349057', '0', '0', '52998']
['09/18/14', '13:00:00', '09/18/14', '13:00:00', 'XXXXXXXXXXX', 'GRP-XXXXXXXXXXX', 'DEFAULT', 'spostmv', '77010644', '0', '0', '20510']
['09/18/14', '14:00:00', '09/18/14', '14:00:00', 'XXXXXXXXXXX', 'GRP-XXXXXXXXXXX', 'DEFAULT', 'spostmv', '78546837', '0', '0', '15008']
['09/18/14', '15:00:00', '09/18/14', '15:00:00', 'XXXXXXXXXXX', 'GRP-XXXXXXXXXXX', 'DEFAULT', 'spostmv', '79770873', '0', '0', '30726']
['09/18/14', '16:00:00', '09/18/14', '16:00:00', 'XXXXXXXXXXX', 'GRP-XXXXXXXXXXX', 'DEFAULT', 'spostmv', '75913522', '0', '0', '23696']
['09/18/14', '17:00:00', '09/18/14', '17:00:00', 'XXXXXXXXXXX', 'GRP-XXXXXXXXXXX', 'DEFAULT', 'spostmv', '19052209', '0', '0', '17656']
```

This is actually what's being printed after the for loop.

```
['09/18/14', '17:00:00', '09/18/14', '17:00:00', 'XXXXXXXXXXX', 'GRP-XXXXXXXXXXX', 'DEFAULT', 'spostmv', '19052209', '0', '0', '17656']
```

Here is my template code:

```
{% for udr_row in udr_rows %}
    {{udr_row}}
{% endfor %}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest a better Title, description for the question. As an example "Rendering a list in a Django template" would be more informative and helps to attract more people to answer the question.

Comment: I'll update it, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing from for loop as

```
rows = []
for udr_rows in reader:
    print udr_rows
    rows.append(udr_rows)
```

so value of `udr_rows` will be last line or `reader`.

Please change your payload to get `reader` instead of `udr_rows`.

```
payload = {'usr': usr, 'usrpw': usrpw, 'response': response, 'response_2': response_2, 'response_udr': response_udr, 'udr_rows': rows,}
```

Comment: When I try to fix it with your solution. Nothing is getting passed to the template. When I try to display udr_rows alone in the template with the for loop I get this: <_csv.reader object at 0x0348DB30>.

Comment: When I tried your updated solution. All I saw as the results were [...][...][...] ... vertically going down.

Answer (score 2):

Put

```
udr_rows = reader
```

After the for...that should make the trick. You are printing only the last value on it

Comment: When I do this, after the for loop I get only:<_csv.reader object at 0x0348DB30>.

Comment: I mean, in your template? You want the full object to iterate in the for in the template (unless i misunderstood and you want only 1 row from the object)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is after you print it to the console with this loop:

```
for udr_rows in reader:
    print udr_rows
```

The file pointer is at the end of the file - which is why nothing gets sent to your template. Convert the reader object directly to a list, and then send it to your template:

```
reader = csv.reader(response_udr)
payload = {'usr': usr,
           'usrpw': usrpw,
           'response': response,
           'response_2': response_2,
           'response_udr': response_udr,
           'udr_rows': list(reader)}
```

You should also use the [`render` shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/shortcuts/), and you don't need to send the response to your template; you should enable the [request context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request) and your templates will automatically get the request object.

---

> This solution sort of works, but I need to grab each list, and not put
>   everything into one list, if that makes sense. When it prints from the
>   for, each is a list I believe. I want to do this so I can stylize the
>   list into tables with headings

What you are getting in the template is a list-of-lists, so it would be very easy for you to create a table with it:

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        ...
        <th>Column N</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      {% for row in udr_rows %}
         <tr>
         {% for item in row %}
            <td>{{ item }}</td>
         {% endfor %}
         </tr>
      {% endfor %}
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This solution sort of works, but I need to grab each list, and not put everything into one list, if that makes sense. When it prints from the for, each is a list I believe. I want to do this so I can stylize the list into tables with headings.